# How can I find a Google BigQuery dataset size, not table sizes?

Tags: google-bigquery

I can see metadata details of tables in BigQuery, but for project estimations I'm hoping to see metadata of the entire dataset.

```
SELECT * From 'dataset'._TABLES_SUMMARY_WHERE size_bytes>0 isn't working for me.
```

Answer (score 34):

```
SELECT SUM(size_bytes) AS bytes 
FROM [yourdataset.__TABLES__]
```

Comment: Nope....I'm getting following error Error: Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 3, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF> ??

Comment: there is no line 3 in above suggested code! can you show what exactly query you are running? btw, have you replaced 'yourdataset' with your actual dataset?

Comment: Make sure you wrap the dataset/table name in bqsql quotes ([ and ]). I added them to the answer above.

Comment: It worked fine for me with the publicdata:samples dataset:

SELECT SUM(size_bytes) AS bytes FROM [publicdata:samples.__TABLES__]

Comment: Guys, Thank you so much, it was indeed a simple case of [ ] missing on the bqsql, doh! Thanks guys :-)

Comment: It worked for me _without_ the square brackets, but not _with_

Comment: I tried with the brackets in Query editor but got an error that said to use the back tick \'.  Like this: SELECT SUM(size_bytes) AS bytes FROM \`publicdata:samples.__TABLES__\`

Comment: @Russ960 - answer was given in 2015 and is for Legacy SQL! That time  - there was no support yet in BigQuery for Standard SQL. Now it has!!! so if you use Standard SQL  use back ticks instead of square brackets!

Answer (score 13):

The previous answer is correct, but I would like to extend the answer.

On BigQuery StandardSQL you can query size by dataset like the following:

```
SELECT
  dataset_id,
  count(*) AS tables,
  SUM(row_count) AS total_rows,
  SUM(size_bytes) AS size_bytes
FROM ( 
  SELECT * FROM `dataset1.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `dataset2.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  ...
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY size_bytes DESC
```

Unfortunately I have not find a way to list all tables for all datasets of a project. Instead I used the `bq`command line to generate all the `SELECT ... UNION ALL` statements:

```
bq ls --format=json | jq -r '.[] | select(.location == "EU") | .id' | sed 's/:/./' | sed 's/\(.*\)/SELECT * FROM `\1.__TABLES__` UNION ALL/'
```

Comment: This answer perfectly helped me counting all bytes in my projects. Thank you. I hope it counted the right order of magnitude :). With `bq --project_id=...  ` one can select a specific project. That way I counted the numbers for 5 projects.

Comment: is there a way to get a month-on-month stats for the tables???

Answer (score 5):

Another convenient way is use [Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/?hl=zh-tw&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=japac-TW-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1009882&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_495210765272-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20BKWS%20-%20EXA%20%7C%20Txt%20%7E%20Operations%20%7E%20Cloud%20Monitoring_mgmt%20-%20monitoring%20google%20cloud-KWID_43700008268946719-kwd-25694252939&userloc_9040379-network_g&utm_term=KW_google%20cloud%20monitoring&gclid=Cj0KCQiAsqOMBhDFARIsAFBTN3eitqbPCZa9M_nJLJe1-ZnyKiUmQQ01jIAV7kjqUc-XtgithDKjEmgaAjcSEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) feature to visualize the size of datasets.

[Monitoring configuration example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6KBm.png)

Comment: this is a fantastic answer because it lets you see size over time

Comment: Great answer. Can find this here.  https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@Luís Bianchin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1046584/lu%c3%ads-bianchin) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955079/13284765), to avoid writing multiple UNION ALL queries, we can use SQL scripting. First selecting all datasets from
`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and then calculate the size for all datasets in a project

```sql
DECLARE
  select_dataset_sql STRING;
DECLARE
  sql STRING;
SET
  select_dataset_sql = (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG("SELECT dataset_id, row_count, size_bytes FROM `"||schema_name||".__TABLES__`"),"UNION ALL ") AS sql
  FROM
    projec-id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA );
SET
  sql = FORMAT("""
  SELECT
    dataset_id,
    COUNT(*) AS tables,
    SUM(row_count) AS total_rows,
    SUM(size_bytes)/1e+6 AS size_mb
  FROM (
    %s
    )
  GROUP BY
    1
  ORDER BY
    size_mb DESC 
"""
,select_dataset_sql 
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* this code will fetch the total datasets size of your bigquery datasest    provided */

import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class BigqueryMigrate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String serviceAccountPath = "C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Desktop\\users\\service_account_json_path_here.json";
        String PROJECTID = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE";

        // Load credentials from the service account JSON file
        GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountPath));

        // Set the credentials and project ID for the BigQuery client
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(PROJECTID).build().getService();


        List<String> datasetsToTraverse = List.of("Your datasets list here");

        final double[] finalsize = {0};
        Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();

        datasetsToTraverse.parallelStream().forEach(datasetId -> {

            Dataset dataset = bigquery.getDataset(datasetId);
            double sizeM = 0;

            Page<Table> pageTable = dataset.list();

            for (Table table : pageTable.getValues()) {
                table = table.reload();

                TableDefinition definition = table.getDefinition();
                if (definition != null && ((StandardTableDefinition) definition).getNumBytes() != null) {
                    double size = ((StandardTableDefinition) definition).getNumBytes();
                    sizeM = sizeM + size;
                }
            }

            while (pageTable.hasNextPage()) {
                Page<Table> nextPage = pageTable.getNextPage();
                for (Table table : nextPage.getValues()) {
                    table = table.reload();

                    TableDefinition definition = table.getDefinition();
                    if (definition != null && ((StandardTableDefinition) definition).getNumBytes() != null) {
                        double size = ((StandardTableDefinition) definition).getNumBytes();
                        sizeM = sizeM + size;

                    }

                }
            }

            double size_kb = sizeM / 1024;
            double size_mb = size_kb / 1024;
            double size_gb = size_mb / 1024;
            double size_tb = size_gb / 1024;

            finalsize[0] = finalsize[0] + size_tb;

            Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();


            map1.put("Total size KB: ", size_kb);
            map1.put("Total size MB: ", size_mb);
            map1.put("Total size GB: ", size_gb);
            map1.put("Total size TB: ", size_tb);

            map.put(datasetId, map1);

            System.out.println(map);

        });

        System.out.println("Total Size :" + finalsize[0]);
        System.out.println("Stopped");

    }

}
```